# PySpark in Eclipse

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

When I run a pyspark code from  Eclipse locally using PyDev, everything is working. However, when it comes to launching a code using remote server (from Eclipse), I am faced with the following problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/analysis/myProject.py", line 40, in <module>
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Spark")
  File "/Users/name/Documents/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/conf.py", line 104, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
  File "/Users/name/Documents/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/context.py", line 245, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway()
  File "/Users/name/Documents/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 76, in launch_gateway
    proc = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, preexec_fn=preexec_func, env=env)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How to configure Eclipse for developing with PySpark using remote server?
The first part of my code:

```
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"]='--master spark://server_ip-address:port --total-executor-cores N --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0 pyspark-shell'

os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/home/user/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6"
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Spark")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
```

May somebody help? I was trying to find some solutions, but no result. Thanks a lot!